# SQL Server Syntax - Using in or like with comma delimited columns

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables where I want to check if a value exists in the second table.
The problem is that in the second table the group field could either be a individual value or a comma delimited value. I need a query to check if the group value exists in table 2 either as a single value or in a comma delimited value

Table 1

| Id | Group |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Group1 |
| 2 | Group2 |
| 3 | Group3 |
| 5 | Group4 |
| 6 | Group4 |
| 7 | Group2 |

Table 2

| Group |
| --- |
| Group1, Group2 |
| Group3 |

The results of the select query would be.

Table 1 Filtered Results

| Id | Group |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Group1 |
| 2 | Group2 |
| 3 | Group3 |
| 7 | Group2 |

Comment: Why not fix your design? Then the problem doesn't exist.

Comment: **Don't put comma-delimited data in columns!** It will come back to bite you. Every. Time. This cries out for an additional table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ideally, you should not store multiple pieces of information in a single column.**

But you can solve this in set-based fashion, using `STRING_SPLIT` in a subquery.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM t1
WHERE t1.[group] IN (
    SELECT TRIM(s.value)
    FROM t2
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(t2.[group], ',') s
    );
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=333178fd14ca0651301bc1e7d5231bff)

Answer (score 0):

Try joining the two tables with a `LIKE` clause, like this:

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE (id INT, [group] VARCHAR(255))
DECLARE @t2 TABLE ([group] VARCHAR(255))

INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES (1,'g1'),(2,'g2'),(3,'g3'),(5,'g4'),(6,'g4'),(7,'g2')
INSERT INTO @t2 VALUES ('g1,g2'),('g3')

SELECT DISTINCT t1.* 
FROM @t1 t1 INNER JOIN @t2 t2 
    ON t2.[group] LIKE '%' + t1.[group] OR t2.[group] LIKE '%' + t1.[group] + ',%'
```

Result:

| id | group |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | g1 |
| 2 | g2 |
| 3 | g3 |
| 7 | g2 |

**UPDATED** to accommodate Larnu's comment to Carlos's post

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
select * from Table1 t1 where exists (
    select * from Table2 t2 where t2.[Group] like '%'+t1.[Group]+'%'
)
```

But be careful!!! "Group" is a keyword in SQL, you should not name a field like that.

UPDATE on Larnu comment:

To avoid `Group1` and `Group10` match, we can do that:

```
select * from Table1 t1 where exists (
    select * from Table2 t2 where (t2.[Group] like '%'+t1.[Group] or t2.[Group] like '%'+t1.[Group]+',%')
)
```

Comment: Careful `Group1` and `Group10` would be matched then. `'GROUP10,GROUP7' LIKE '%Group1%'` is TRUE.